# Interaction between modules in python package

Tags: python, python-module

For example, I have package X, which contains modules *module1* and *module2*. In *module1* I have a class MyClass, which I want to use in *module2*. Can I just do this in *module2*:

```
import module1

a = module1.MyClass()
```

?

I mean usage of relative path to module. In python documentation(in " Intra-package References" section) says, that in python2.7 we can use "import module1", but for python 3 they say, that we can use "from module1 import MyClass". But there are no information, is this first form prohibited. And this is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try it out?

This code won't work. It needs to be

```
import module1

a = module1.MyClass()
```

I suggest reading up on packages and import. They can get more confusing when your package starts to grow.

Comment: Sorry, for lost "module1." part. But I mean usage of relative path to module. In python documentation(in " Intra-package References" section) says, that in python2.7 we can use "import module1", but for python 3 they say, that we can use "from module1 import MyClass". But there are no information, is this first form prohibited. And this is my question.

Comment: "import module1" would import the entire module. You would be able to reach all code in the file using "module1.XXX".

Using "from module1 import MyClass" only gives you MyClass.

Python version isn't important for this, It should work in both.